# custom-marker from ng-map with ng-repeat gives me $digest loop errors while still working properly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps, angularjs-digest, ng-map

I currently use [this](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to get custom markers on a map.

I got it working without errors on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IAqy4ANy03aVGe3WB0C?p=preview), but not on my own site (even though I'm using the same script src links)

On my own page ng-repeat works, but it gives 2 very long errors informing me about a $digest loop
[image: error]

This is my list:

```
$scope.list = [{ name: 'test', pos: [41, -87] }, { name: 'test2', pos: [40, -86] }];
```

And this the HTML:

```
<ng-map zoom-to-include-markers="auto" style="height:200px;width:400px;">
    <marker ng-repeat="item in list" position="{{item.pos}}"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

The above doesn't give errors, but

```
<ng-map zoom-to-include-markers="auto" style="height:200px;width:400px;">
    <custom-marker ng-repeat="item in list" position="{{item.pos}}">
        <div style="background-color:white;border: 1px solid black;">this is a test</div>
    </custom-marker>
</ng-map>
```

does. It also gives me 2 extra errors everytime I add an item to the list, but it still works properly.

I have no idea why it works on plunker but not on my own site, I serve it using ASP.NET 5, using the same versions. On my own site also use ng-animate, ng-resource and a bunch of stuff that isn't angular related, but that shouldn't matter. (I hope)

Incase you need it, my controller is using these:

```
function ($scope, $rootScope, restData, NgMap) {
```

and app module is using this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngMap'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself.

I tried using [this](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/custom-marker-ng-repeat.html) to solve my problem before I asked this question, but I probably forgot some part of it since it works the second time I tried it.

You need to use

```
$scope.positions = angular.copy(data)
```

and bind on that seperate 'positions' variable and copy it if you want to rebind, you can't bind directly from the frontend on the data itself.